# Is there a way to legally extend the evaluation period?

Tags: windows-8, license

Is it possible to rearm Windows 8 evaluation copy when it is close to expiry of 90 days again and again after every three months?

Comment: Extending an evaluation period is not inherently piracy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Windows 8 Forums](http://www.forumswindows8.com/info/extending-windows-8-trial-164.html) and [some blog](http://www.jholu.com/2012/01/02/extend-trial-of-windows-8-windows-7-or-vista/), issuing `slmgr -rearm` on an elevated command prompt (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd>) will reset your evaluation period to 90 days.

I just gave that a try in a VM. After a reboot it told me my licence is expired. But after another reboot, my evaluation period is reset to 90 days:

[image]

Comment: On previous versions you could only do this 3 times. I do believe the evaluation copy also has a *hard* limit on how long it can be used. I personally wouldn't consider this a long term solution.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Who would consider an evaluation of an operating system that cost money a long term solution.  The evaluation is a short term solution to evaluate the product.  I am only being half serious by writting this comment.  In other words there isn't a long term solution to extending the evaluation of Windows 8 Enterprise, the only solution, is to purchase the product itself and reinstall.

Comment: Well,  the technical part of it is on topic, IMO, the ethical part (MS does allow this, right?) and business part of it is a whole another story. Just wanted to make it clear that its unlikely he could keep extending the evaluation period.